# Why does Visual Studio create a new certificate every time I publish a UWP packaging project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp, win-universal-app

When publishing, a Test folder is created with an `msixbundle` file for installing the app on my computer to test the app. It also creates a `cer` file. As far as I remember, the certificate didn't use to change. Now, every time I publish it, I need to install the certificate again because it has changed.

Is this a change in Visual Studio and there's nothing I can do about it, or is it something that I accidentally changed in the settings and I can change back?

Comment: Open the `Package.appxmanifest` and select a certificate to use under the `Packaging` tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which certificate to use when signing the package by selecting a PFX file under the **Packaging** tab in the app manifest designer in Visual Studio.

If you click on the "Choose Certificate..." button, you'll also have the option to create a self-signed test certificate.

You can also do this using the `New-SelfSignedCertificate` PowerShell cmdlet as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/june/devops-msix-the-modern-way-to-deploy-desktop-apps-on-windows?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

In a previous version of Visual Studio, there was indeed a default PFX file included in the project template but it seems to have been removed.